# Vue, mapping only the value of options to v-model

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-multiselect

I have a vue-multiselect instance that I'm trying to map in a way where I can take the value from the 'contact_data' index of the array I'm passing into the options and store it into an array without the index name. Basically, I need my copyUsers array to look like:

```
0:
  "email@mail.com"
1:
  "new@mail.com"
```

But right now it's:

```
0:
  "contact_data":"email@mail.com"
```

Anyway, I've used the spread operator on my `response.data` object which initially got the options into my multiselect, but now I've tried to map the index of my options to only push the value into the array but it's not working and now I'm not even getting any options to show up in my multiselect.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
    <multiselect 
    v-model="copyUsers" 
    @search-change="val => searchCopiedUsers(val)"
    :options="copyUsersOptions.map(i => i.contact_data)" //changed this from copyUsersOptions
    :multiple="true" 
    :loading="loading"
    placeholder="Enter user(s) to be copied" 
    label="contact_data"
    track-by="contact_data">
</multiselect>


data() {
        return {
            loading: false,
            copyUsers: [],
            copyUsersOptions: [],
        }
    },
  
    methods: {
        searchCopiedUsers: function(val) {
              console.log('searched for', val);
              if (val) {
                this.loading = true;

                axios.get('/ticket/users/search',{params: {query: val}})
                .then(response => {
                    
                    this.copyUsersOptions = [...response.data];

                    console.info(this.copyUsersOptions);
                    console.log('here are the users');
                    console.log(this.copyUsers);

                    
                  })
                  .catch(function(error) {
                    this.loading = false;
                    // handle error
                    console.log(error)
                  })
                  .finally(function() {
                    this.loading = false;
                  })

              } else {
                this.copyUsersOptions = [];
              }
        }
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Full object if I dump response.data

```
1: {contact_data: "test@mail.com"}
2: {contact_data: "johndoe@msn.com"}
3: {contact_data: "res@gmail.com"}
4: {contact_data: "info@globe.net"}
5: {contact_data: "testing@yahoo.com"}
```

Comment: Can you post a full copy of your object? It appears that what you posted, looks like an array that is formatted as an object. But that does not quite explain why after using the spread operator it is acting almost like a class

Comment: Yes I can post the object shortly, I'll try and just copy/paste directly from the console

Comment: @SuitBoyApps Thanks, I just updated with the object straight from response.data, before doing the spread at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see what is going on, when I answered you yesterday I did not have a clear understanding of what your data looks like.

Now understanding that your response data looks something like this

```js
{
    1: { contact_data: "test@mail.com" },
    2: { contact_data: "johndoe@msn.com" },
    3: { contact_data: "res@gmail.com" },
    4: { contact_data: "info@globe.net" },
    5: { contact_data: "testing@yahoo.com" },
}
```

I can see that it is an object of objects. In order to transform this into an array. We will get an array of all the keys in that object using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys).

From the data given this will return

```js
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Then we will use [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to iterate over the array from `Object.keys()` to create an array of `contact_data`.

```js
Object.keys(response.data)
      .map((key) => response[key].contact_data)
```

[Here is a sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-68597913-wsmsn?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue)

Putting it all together, your Axios call would then become

```
axios.get('/ticket/users/search',{params: {query: val}})
    .then(response => {
        
        this.copyUsersOptions = Object.keys(res.data)
                                   .map((key) => 
                                      response.data[key].contact_data
                                   )

        console.info(this.copyUsersOptions);
        console.log('here are the users');
        console.log(this.copyUsers);

        
        })
```

Comment: That makes total sense now! Your original solution worked for what I was needing, but I ended up needing to match the returned data in a different convention and this is where I was hitting a road block. Thanks so much!